# In Go, why is JSON null sometimes not passed to UnmarshalJSON for decoding?

Tags: json, go

Go provides the `encoding/json.Unmarshaler` interface so types can control the way they are decoded from JSON. In almost all cases, the encoded JSON value is passed directly to the `UnmarshalJSON` method, but not if the `Unmarshaler` is a pointer and the JSON value is `null`. In that case, the pointer is set to `nil` without calling `UnmarshalJSON` at all. Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type T string

func (v *T) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if b[0] == 'n' {
        *v = "null"
    } else {
        *v = "not null"
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var a struct {
        T   T
        PT1 *T
        PT2 *T
    }
    a.PT1 = nil // just to be explicit
    a.PT2 = new(T)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"T":null,"PT1":"foo","PT2":null}`), &a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("a.T is %#v\n", a.T)
    if a.PT1 == nil {
        fmt.Println("a.PT1 is nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("a.PT1 points to %#v\n", *a.PT1)
    }
    if a.PT2 == nil {
        fmt.Println("a.PT2 is nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("a.PT2 points to %#v\n", *a.PT2)
    }
}
```

I expected this to print

```
a.T is "null"
a.PT1 points to "not null"
a.PT2 points to "null"
```

Instead, it prints

```
a.T is "null"
a.PT1 points to "not null"
a.PT2 is nil
```

So `json.Unmarshal` allocates a new `T` for `a.PT1`, which is initially `nil`. But it sets `a.PT2` to `nil` without calling `UnmarshalJSON`, even though `a.PT2` was not `nil`. Why?

Comment: Yes, if you have the json string "null" you're going to get the null value for your reference type (not in Go, in most languages). Please don't ask obvious questions and then answer them yourself 5 minutes later.

Comment: Maybe I'm dumber than most, but I spent the better part of a day figuring out why this wasn't a bug in the standard library. It would have been obvious if I had not been using the Go interface specifically designed to override the default decoding rules.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. My comment was made on the basis of you answering the question as soon as you asked it. Perhaps it will prove helpful to others. I would consider it a pretty common thing to run into deserializing json though.

Answer (score 1):

This is because setting the pointer to `nil` is the most common way to handle a JSON `null`, and there is no way for an `UnmarshalJSON` method of `*T` to do that on its own. If `UnmarshalJSON` were called in this case, you would have to define `(**T).UnmarshalJSON` to set the `*T` to `nil`. This would make the most common case very awkward.

If you don't want JSON `null` to become Go `nil`, don't use a pointer.